# How to make "Start" button visible after clicking "Reset" button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

I'm making a timer with jQuery. When you press the "Reset" button, it is supposed to make the "Start" button visible again.

I am getting this error:

- Clicking the "Reset" button:
  The selector "#reset" does not render the expected css for property "display": expected 'inline-block' to deeply equal 'none'

Here is my html:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <title>Interactivity</title>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles/site.css"/>
  <script src="scripts/jquery-3.2.1.min.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/formatTime.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/times.js"></script>
  <script src="scripts/reset.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  <div id="text">
    <p>
      Can you internally count 45 seconds precisely?
    </p>
  </div>
  <button id="start">Start Timer</button>
  <button id="stop" style="display: none;">Stop Timer</button>
  <button id="reset" style="display: none;">Reset Timer</button>
  <span id="time_started" class="hidden" style="display: none;">Timer Started</span>
  <span id="time_ended" class="hidden">Timer Ended</span>
</body>
</html>
```

Here is my css:

```
body {
  background-color: white;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  margin: 200px auto 0;
  max-width: 900px;
}

h1 {
  text-align: center;
}

div {
  margin-bottom: 50px;
}

.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

Here is reset.js:

```
// reset everything
$("#reset").on('click',function() {
    $(".results").addClass("hidden");
    $("#reset").addClass("hidden");
    $("#start").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#time_started").addClass("hidden");
    $("#time_ended").addClass("hidden");
});
```

Here is formatTime.js:

```
// formats the current date/time so that it reads as hh:mm:ss PM/AM
function formatTime(time) {
  var
    end_time,
        formatted_time,
        formatted_end_time,
        start_time,
    hour = 12,
    minute = 10,
    second = 10,
    meridies;
  
    hour = time.getHours();
    if (hour>12) {
        hour = hour-12;
        meridies = "PM";
    } else {
        meridies = "AM";
    }

    minute = time.getMinutes();
    if (minute<10) {
        minute = "0"+minute;
    }

    second = time.getSeconds();
    if (second<10) {
        second = "0"+second;
    }

    return hour+":"+minute+":"+second+" "+meridies;
}
```

Here is times.js:

```
/* global formatTime: true */
/* Please do not remove the comment above. */

// timer to calculate the starting and stopping clicks
var start_time;
var formatted_time;
var end_time;
var formatted_end_time;
var time_change;

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#start").on('click',function() {
    $("#start").hide();
    $("#stop").show();
    $("#time_started").hide();
    $("#time_ended").hide();
    end_time = new Date();
    start_time = new Date();
    formatted_time = formatTime(start_time);
  });

  $("#stop").on('click',function() {
    $("#stop").hide();
    $("#reset").show();
    $("#time_started").hide();
    $("#time_ended").show();
    end_time = new Date();
    formatted_end_time = formatTime(end_time);
    $("body").append("<p class='results'>You started at "+formatted_time+".</p>");
    $("body").append("<p class='results'>You finished at "+formatted_end_time+".</p>");
    time_change = end_time-start_time;
    $("body").append("<p class='results'>You counted "+(time_change/1000)+" seconds.</p>");
    $("body").append("<p class='results'>You are off by "+(time_change/1000-45)+" seconds.</p>");
  });
 
});
```

Comment: Are you missing a display class? It looks like its suppose to remove the hidden class from start but I don't see where the hidden class is being appended to the start-element.

Comment: try adding the class attribute with the class hidden to the start element like (class="hidden") <-- it looks like it is suppose to toggle this class, but it doesn't appear to have this class appended to it at all... Unless the hide() function appends it. Do you know how JQueries hide method works?

Comment: Hi @NodeSamurai, thank you for the quick response! Do you have an example of how I can implement this? I'm new to js >_<

Comment: Let me load this in my editor, if im going to answer the question, it has to be a solution, gimme a sec

Comment: Okay so I came back to tell you what @ksav already did. Except there is one other thing I found gives an error. All your JavaScript is at the top of the page, and the buttons are loading before the Jquery does. I am using the CDN so you might not experience this, but if I clicked to fast I would get errors telling me that the page haddnt had time to load the layout yet. When I put the scripts below the markup I wasn't able to recreate the error. Just to be sure I put the scripts on top again, and I got the error again. Just FYI.

Comment: You guys are awesome, thank you both!

Answer (score 1):

Avoid mixing `addClass()` / `removeClass()` vs `hide()` / `show()`.

It should be obvious what `addClass()` / `removeClass()` do. `hide()` / `show()` add and remove inline css styles to achieve a similar end result (but inline styles will *always* take precedence).

```js
$(function() {
  $("#reset").on("click", function() {
    $(".results").remove();
    $("#reset").addClass("hidden");
    $("#time_ended").addClass("hidden");
    $("#start").removeClass("hidden");
  });

  // timer to calculate the starting and stopping clicks
  var start_time;
  var formatted_time;
  var end_time;
  var formatted_end_time;
  var time_change;

  $("#start").on("click", function() {
    $("#start").addClass("hidden");
    $("#stop").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#time_started").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#time_ended").addClass("hidden");

    end_time = new Date();
    start_time = new Date();
    formatted_time = formatTime(start_time);
  });

  $("#stop").on("click", function() {
    // $("#stop").hide();
    $("#stop").addClass("hidden");
    // $("#reset").show();
    $("#reset").removeClass("hidden");
    // $("#time_started").hide();
    $("#time_started").addClass("hidden");
    // $("#time_ended").show();
    $("#time_ended").removeClass("hidden");
    end_time = new Date();
    formatted_end_time = formatTime(end_time);
    $("body").append(
      "<p class='results'>You started at " + formatted_time + ".</p>"
    );
    $("body").append(
      "<p class='results'>You finished at " + formatted_end_time + ".</p>"
    );
    time_change = end_time - start_time;
    $("body").append(
      "<p class='results'>You counted " + time_change / 1000 + " seconds.</p>"
    );
    $("body").append(
      "<p class='results'>You are off by " +
      (time_change / 1000 - 45) +
      " seconds.</p>"
    );
  });
});

function formatTime(time) {
  var end_time,
    formatted_time,
    formatted_end_time,
    start_time,
    hour = 12,
    minute = 10,
    second = 10,
    meridies;

  hour = time.getHours();
  if (hour > 12) {
    hour = hour - 12;
    meridies = "PM";
  } else {
    meridies = "AM";
  }

  minute = time.getMinutes();
  if (minute < 10) {
    minute = "0" + minute;
  }

  second = time.getSeconds();
  if (second < 10) {
    second = "0" + second;
  }

  return hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " " + meridies;
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
  <p>
    Can you internally count 45 seconds precisely?
  </p>
</div>
<button id="start">Start Timer</button>
<button id="stop" class="hidden">Stop Timer</button>
<button id="reset" class="hidden">Reset Timer</button>
<span id="time_started" class="hidden">Timer Started</span>
<span id="time_ended" class="hidden">Timer Ended</span>
```

Also, be careful when appending new content on every round and then just hiding it at the end (instead of actually removing it). You would end up with unnecessarily duplicated html.

Alternatively you could add the `.results` in the starting html with a class of `.hidden` to use the same hide/show method for everything.

```js
$(function() {
  $("#reset").on("click", function() {
    $(".results").addClass("hidden");
    $("#reset").addClass("hidden");
    $("#time_ended").addClass("hidden");
    $("#start").removeClass("hidden");
  });

  // timer to calculate the starting and stopping clicks
  var start_time;
  var formatted_time;
  var end_time;
  var formatted_end_time;
  var time_change;

  $("#start").on("click", function() {
    $("#start").addClass("hidden");
    $("#stop").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#time_started").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#time_ended").addClass("hidden");

    end_time = new Date();
    start_time = new Date();
    formatted_time = formatTime(start_time);
  });

  $("#stop").on("click", function() {
    $("#stop").addClass("hidden");
    $("#reset").removeClass("hidden");
    $("#time_started").addClass("hidden");
    $("#time_ended").removeClass("hidden");
    $(".results").removeClass("hidden");

    end_time = new Date();
    formatted_end_time = formatTime(end_time);
    time_change = end_time - start_time;

    $('#results-time-started span').text(formatted_time);
    $('#results-time-ended span').text(formatted_end_time);
    $('#results-time-counted span').text(time_change / 1000);
    $('#results-time-off-by span').text(time_change / 1000 - 45);
  });
});

function formatTime(time) {
  var end_time,
    formatted_time,
    formatted_end_time,
    start_time,
    hour = 12,
    minute = 10,
    second = 10,
    meridies;

  hour = time.getHours();
  if (hour > 12) {
    hour = hour - 12;
    meridies = "PM";
  } else {
    meridies = "AM";
  }

  minute = time.getMinutes();
  if (minute < 10) {
    minute = "0" + minute;
  }

  second = time.getSeconds();
  if (second < 10) {
    second = "0" + second;
  }

  return hour + ":" + minute + ":" + second + " " + meridies;
}
```

```css
.hidden {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="text">
  <p>
    Can you internally count 45 seconds precisely?
  </p>
</div>
<button id="start">Start Timer</button>
<button id="stop" class="hidden">Stop Timer</button>
<button id="reset" class="hidden">Reset Timer</button>
<span id="time_started" class="hidden">Timer Started</span>
<span id="time_ended" class="hidden">Timer Ended</span>


<p id='results-time-started' class='hidden results'>You started at <span></span>.</p>
<p id='results-time-ended' class='hidden results'>You finised at <span></span>.</p>
<p id='results-time-counted' class='hidden results'>You counted <span></span> seconds.</p>
<p id='results-time-off-by' class='hidden results'>You are off by <span></span> seconds.</p>
```

Comment: You're welcome. Feel free to upvote and accept this answer if it helped you